# Upsampling on pandas panel data

Tags: python, pandas, panel-data

I have data that looks like this

```
    date        ticker  x    y
0   2018-01-31  ABC     1    5
1   2019-01-31  ABC     2    6
2   2018-01-31  XYZ     3    7
3   2019-01-31  XYZ     4    8
```

So it is a panel of yearly observations. I want to upsample to a monthly frequency and forward fill the new observations. So ABC would look like

```
    date        ticker  x     y
0   2018-01-31  ABC     1     5
1   2018-02-28  ABC     1     5
...
22  2019-11-30  ABC     2     6
23  2019-12-31  ABC     2     6
```

Notice that I want to fill through the last year, not just up until the last date.

Right now I am doing something like

```
newidx = df.groupby('ticker')['date'].apply(lambda x: 
    pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.min(),x.max()+YearEnd(1),freq='M'))).reset_index()
newidx.drop('level_1',axis=1,inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(newidx,df,on=['date','ticker'],how='left')
```

This is obviously a terrible way to do this. It's really slow, but it works. What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: I dont think a faster way might be possible, but a more concise might be :)

Comment: Another thing I realized that your approach doesn't give the desired result  due to the mis-aligned date in the two dataframes.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach might be slow because you need `groupby`, then `merge`. Let's try another option with `reindex` so you only need `groupby`:

```
(df.set_index('date')
   .groupby('ticker')
   .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(x.index.min(),x.index.max()+YearEnd(1),freq='M'),
                              method='ffill'))
   .reset_index('ticker', drop=True)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma you're right. I didn't realized OP wants to fill all the next year. Updated.

Comment: .. No problem ;)